# How to bind to an attached property of a subproperty of a static property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have the following code

```
public static class StaticClass
{
    public static Instance Inst { get; set; }
}

public class Instance
{
    public Button Butt { get; set; }
}
```

I need to bind to `Grid.Row` property attached to `Butt` button. I tried this:

```
{Binding Source={x:Static local:StaticClass.Inst.Butt}, Path=(Grid.Row)}
```

But it doesn't work because `Butt` is not static property. Usually I use x:Static to bind to static property and write the rest in Path, but in this case Path contains attached property. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Please dont abberiviate Button to Butt, it makes me giggle. Think of the repercussions, such as `Butt is inaccesable due to its protection level` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need this, because, as you said, `Butt` is not static:

```
{Binding Source={x:Static local:StaticClass.Inst}, Path=Butt.(Grid.Row)}
```

That is, make `Butt` part of your `Path`, not part of the `Source`.

Comment: Wow! Didn't think I can use attached property syntax like this